# Using Image Slider Overlaps search area

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I'm using an image slider - NivoSlider, and for some reason, the search area, which normally slightly overlaps the image is now behind the image. I was wondering if somebody had some ideas on how to change this?

NOTE: I've tried using z-index, and it just makes the image slider disappear altogether because something is in front of it.

http://www.web-want.com/estate/    - you can see for yourself here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Fixed your issue. Use this CSS:

```
#main_home {position: relative; z-index: 1;}
#search_area {position: relative; z-index: 5;}
```

Add this to the end of `style.css`  or just update in these lines: `470`.

#### Screenshot:

[image: Z-Index Issue]

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure about z-index?  I've added;

```
position: relative;
z-index: 2000;
```

to #search_area in style.css line 470 and it's sorted it out.  I'm not sure exactly which smallest z-index would do it, I just chose 2000 as a big number, but it's working.